# Connect to Samba Share across OpenVPN tunnel

Tags: centos, samba, remote, openvpn

I've recently setup OpenVPN for remote connection to our CentOS 6 file server.

```
Server Static IP: 10.0.0.66
Remote OpenVPN IP: 10.8.0.1
```

However when using the OpenVPN connection I am unable to access the Samba share which would normally be accessed using 10.0.0.66 from inside the local network.

I have made the following adjustments to the smb.conf file according to the OpenVPN Website

```
[global]
    unix charset = UTF-8
    dos charset = CP932
    workgroup = WORKGROUP
    server string = Samba Server Version %v
    # include 10.8.0.0/24 for OpenVPN
    hosts allow = 10.0.0.0/100 10.8.0.0/24 127.0.0.1 
    interfaces = 10.0.0.0/100 10.8.0.0/24
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    max log size = 50
    security = share
    passdb backend = tdbsam

[Share]
    path = /samba/share01
    writable = yes
    browsable = yes
    guest ok = yes
    guest only = yes
    create mode = 0777
    directory mode = 0777
```

Then I try to access the Samba share using 10.8.0.1 although it doesn't seem to have worked, Is there something I am missing?

*UPDATE*

The issue has been resolved

I made some slight changes to the smb.conf file, the one above is the latest.
The other issue was how the share was being accessed.

When mapping the network location I had to specify the share I wanted to connect to

```
\\10.8.0.1\Share
```

Then it brought it up just fine.

Thanks to everyone for their help

Comment: What are the routes and local IP address on the [remote] client side?

Comment: Are you sure Server IP is 10.8.0.1? Looks like that address might be the GW address and to access the samba share you should not change any IP in you smb.conf, just make sure routes are OK after establishing the VPN connection.

Comment: Before the Samba share was required the server had always been accessed through ssh to 10.8.0.1 and that ssh connection still works

Comment: The client network is on the IP range 192.168.20.0/100 the client making the successful ssh connection is using the IP 192.168.20.13

Answer (score 0):

This [most probably] is a routing issue.

Your Samba server, as far as the remote part is concerned, is accessed from `192.168.20.0/100` so here are two possibilities:

- either route `192.168.20.0/100` traffic through the OpenVPN interface on the server — it does require a change in `smb.conf` to allow access from `192.168.20.0/100` though;
- or you can just NAT (actually `masquerade`) traffic coming from the `192.168.20.0/100` network on your OpenVPN server interface using `iptables`.

The latter option should require no change in `smb.conf`.